# Basic toggle for a Chrome Exstension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, toggle, togglebutton

I cannot believe I am still have basic programming problems... I know the basics, but still have a hard time implementing the logic I think of. Anyways

I am building this basic Chrome Extension that has one JavaScript file and it does work! The only issue is that once I click the icon it is forever on, that is until I remove it. I want to add a basic toggle functionality, but I am having difficulty getting a working prototype. Here is a couple of my ideas:

```
var toggle == 1; // or true, i.e. clicked
if (functionName() == 1) {
    function functionName() {
        Do whatever it is when clicked;
        blah blah blah;
        } else if (functionName() == 0) {
            Turn off;
        } else {};
}

switch(toggle)
{
    case 1:
        Do whatever it is when clicked;
        blah blah blah;
        break;
case 2:
        Turn off;
         break;
default:
        error;
        break;
}
```

If both if statement and switch statement had a different order, say case 1 and 2 were swapped, I do not think it would be a difference. I do not think a switch statement would be the best way because there is no more than two options, on or off.

What about a while loop to change the conditions of the extension? I do know the modulo operator, and code could be written like:

- 1 % 2 = False,
- 2 % 2 = True,
- 3 % 2 = False, etc

  Then a basic if-statement could work....

  something like:

  ```
  var i = 1;
  while (i % 2 == 1) {
       Do whatever it is when clicked;
       blah blah blah;
       i++;
       }
  ```

  Does anybody have an idea of the best way to do this? I have played with the jQuery .toggle() event, but I do not think this would make since. I have nothing in the html document and only a JavaScript file. It makes no since loading the library and then using the jQuery selector`$("chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function)")` when simple JavaScript can be used.  Plus I do not even know if that would be the right selector...

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

For the record I found the [sample](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html) extensions useless when it comes to something that should  not be complicated.

Thanks!

UPDATE code with my function in background.js:

```
function trigger() {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if (windowId != chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active:true, windowId:windowId }, function(tabs) {
            if (tabs.length == 1) {
                var tab = tabs[0];
                chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
}
var functionOn = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    if (functionOn === false) {
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    trigger();
                    });
                functionOn = true;
            } else if (functionOn === true) {
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    //nothing...
                });
                functionOn = false;
            }
```

The if statement does not work at the moment, my exstension works with this call instead of the if statement at the end:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    trigger();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a super detailed answer without knowing exactly what is supposed to be toggled, but in a nutshell you just need to add something like this to your background script:

```
var functionOn = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    if (functionOn === false) {
        doSomething();
        functionOn = true;
    } else {
        functionOn = false;
        // Don't do anything.
    }
});
```

By putting the variable "functionOn" in the background page the state is persistent. You may already be aware of this, but to create a background script you simply add this to the manifest file:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do with the toggle, but the doSomething() would basically be whatever action you're trying to perform, whether it's injecting code via a content script or showing a popup, etc.

Comment: The logic between the variable functionOn is hard to understand. I perceive that the code written automatically sets the var to false. If that is the case why trigger the function when it is false? The boolean logic above has a fade understanding to me. Also, can there only be one if option? I guess specifying the var in the beginning of the else portion. O, and the === once vs =? confusing... I updated the post with my attempt to make this sound easier to me.